# Match Words After n Spaces Using sed/awk

Tags: regex, sed, awk

If I have a string that is like this:

> word_1 something test

Is there any way I can get the second or the third word using `sed`/`awk`?

Comment: Grep is not the best tool for this.  Have a look at sed or awk.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Changed the question to `sed`/`awk`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the third word of every line, then use `cut -f 3 file_name`.  If you want the third word only if the first word matches a particular string `awk '/^word_1/ { print $3; }' file_name` or something like that (it's been a while since I've used awk, so I have to look up the syntax before I use it).

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the second or third word of each line, I'd just use `awk` like this:

```
awk '{ print $2 }' file.txt
```

for the second word, or with `$3` instead of `$2` for the third, etc.

@paul-tomblin's suggestion with `cut` is also fine, though my take is that if something is simple enough to do with `awk`, I'd use that rather than spend time and brain cells figuring out just what cryptic option I need to use with some-other-random-Posix-command. That is, I think it's worthwhile to concentrate one's energy on learning the more general tools (such as `awk`) really well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to print words after n spaces using `awk`. If you have the number of spaces saved in a bash variable, you could do this:

```
spaces=0
awk -v n=$spaces '{ for (i=n+1; i<=NF; i++) printf (i!=NF) ? $i" " : $i"\n" }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
word_1 something test
```

---

```
spaces=1
awk -v n=$spaces '{ for (i=n+1; i<=NF; i++) printf (i!=NF) ? $i" " : $i"\n" }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
something test
```

---

```
spaces=2
awk -v n=$spaces '{ for (i=n+1; i<=NF; i++) printf (i!=NF) ? $i" " : $i"\n" }' file.txt
```

Result:

```
test
```

Comment: Also, you man want to set the field separator to a single space. You can use this flag: `-F " "`, so that the code will look like `awk -F " " -v n=...`. Otherwise `awk` sees any amount of whitespace as a field separator. HTH.

Comment: This seems overly complicated.

Comment: @Bernhard: I think the OP is looking to print words after _n_ spaces although it is not clear as to what a 'space' is. Is this a single space or an unknown amount of whitespace? I have taken the word literally in my answer and have added an option for a single space in my first comment. I have assumed the OP has a basic understanding of `awk`/`sed`, but may not have considered using a `for` loop. The `printf` statement and variable inputs are just bells and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo {a..z} | sed -r 's/(\s*(\S*)){10}.*/\2/'
j
```

Where `{10}` can be any number e.g. `{2}` would return `b`

For high numbered words `awk` is a much more efficient.